Running a wall wart at 24VAC
I'm working on a HVAC project and I need 6-30VDC to power a XY-J05 module.  24VAC is everywhere, but one side is also "common" and used as a reference for a DC measurement.
Anyway, after scouring the internet for a cheap isolated power supply that will accept 24VAC as an input, I decided to just try powering a random 8.5V wall wart from my pile with 24VAC and it worked.  This seems to provide the isolation I need (since the negative output will inherently be tied back to one of the lines of the A/C input).  But is it a good idea?  Obviously the wall wart wasn't designed to work/start at this low of an input voltage, but maybe it isn't surprising that it works anyway?
Is this a terrible idea?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm a little concerned that the relay on that module probably doesn't provide safety isolation

"24 VAC is everywhere" and none of the usual mains voltages?

@greybeard Entirely possible. Large HVAC projects may be full of 24V valves, dampers, and sensors, but 120/208/240 may only be present at large loads (compressors, fans) as a switched supply, or not at all if run at 480V.

It's not a great idea to depend on it unless you can evaluate it completely and that's unlikely to be possible.
At low input voltage the high voltage semiconductors are working at their hardest in terms of current and the reservoir capacitor is seeing the highest ripple current. Even if you put it on a variac, connect it to an electronic load, and vary the temperature to test the unit over the expected range of conditions and load currents (both operating and starting), those factors could shorten the life significantly.
Most good SMPS designs have undervoltage lockout- and it's there to protect the semiconductors etc., but it may not be well implemented in a cheap supply.
If the presence of high voltage is not a concern, you could operate a 120:24 transformer in reverse and give your adapter a voltage it is designed for.

Thanks - I think I'll just go with a wall-wart plugged into 120V.  Using the existing 24VAC isn't a strict requirement, I just thought it would make for a cleaner solution.
I could potentially use a 1:1 transformer, rectifier + buck converter combo, but at that point I've just built a (crappy) power supply and I should probably just use the mains and a wall-wart.
